# RHEL: Creating stable names for network interfaces

Tags: linux, rhel, devices, ethernet

We have a RHEL 5.5 box with 8 interfaces. And the `eth` interface naming is flip flopping. Sometimes `eth0` comes up on physical port 7th, and sometimes on another physical port.

We want the naming to be as per the sequence of PCI BUS. I did the research and found that

```
cat /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000\:00\:1e.0/0000\:07\:07.0/net\:eth0/address\
```

This locations have the mac address of the `eth` devices. So If I get "address" in sequence from this pci bus locations and put them in `ifconfig-eth0` to `ifconfig-eth7` in order of PCI BUS location, my `eth` naming will be stable.

I tried:

```
find /sys/devices/ -name "address"
```

but it does not bring any results. I don't know why…

Any help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried including the MAC addresses in the different ifcfg-ethX files for the various ethernet devices? Additionally you can control which device get's which ethX handle through udev's `60-net.rules` file.

#### For example

```
# /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

# Intel Corporation 82573E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
DHCPCLASS=
HWADDR=00:30:48:56:A6:2E
IPADDR=10.10.10.15
NETMASK=255.255.255.192
ONBOOT=yes
```

Then in the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-net.rules`:

```
KERNEL=="eth*", SYSFS{address}=="00:30:48:56:A6:2E", NAME="eth0"
```

I believe this information is used to keep the devices configured consistently from boot to boot.

#### Configuring more than one ethX device

To deal with more devices simply setup each devices corresponding `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX` file, and add another line to the `60-net.rules` file.

```
KERNEL=="eth*", SYSFS{address}=="00:30:48:56:A6:2E", NAME="eth0"
KERNEL=="eth*", SYSFS{address}=="00:30:48:56:A6:2F", NAME="eth1"
```

The above is how you do it in CentOS 5.X. The file changes in CentOS 6.x to `70-persistent-net.rules`, and the format is slightly different too:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="54:52:00:ff:ff:dd", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

#### References

- [keeping eth0 as ETH0. - pwrusr.com blog](http://www.pwrusr.com/tag/eth0eth0rm-etcudevrules-d70-persistent-net-rules)

Answer (score 2):

So far as I know , you need a relatively new release. RHEL 6 *seems* to support this ([Consistent Network Device Naming](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/appe-Consistent_Network_Device_Naming.html)) though it does need to be [specifically enabled](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-Consistent_Network_Device_Naming-Enabling_and_Disabling.html) on most systems. [Fedora 15+](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Consistent-names-for-network-interfaces-1180510.html) also does this, and, by Fedora 17, it seems to be the default mode.

I don't know exactly when this change was completely adopted and, more important to this question, if there is any way to backport this to the RHEL 5 series. This is a start, at least.

Comment: Two addendums: RHEL6 does the persistent naming via udev rule (in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`) so doing so in RHEL5 shouldn't be too hard. Also, the Fedora method is a little different in that it uses a deterministic algorithm when naming interfaces that is different than the `eth*` naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

You should get hardware address by:

```
ifconfig -a | grep HWaddr
```

Or perhaps:

```
tail -v /sys/devices/*/*/net/eth*/address
# or
tail -v /sys/devices/*/*/*/net/eth*/address
```

*`find` should have matched.*

<strike>Also check:</strike>

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

*Se comments below*.

Comment: 70-persistent-net.rules doesn't exist in CentOS/RHEL 5.X. It's new in CentOS/RHEL6.x.

Comment: @slm: Nothing to test on here, but are you sure? Ref: http://www.adminlinux.org/2010/09/persistent-eth-interface-names.html

Comment: The name 70-persistent-net.rules isn't really special so you could use it, adding 5.x syntax udev lines to it, but I have several dozen 5.x and 6.x and it's not on any of the 5.x boxes. Additionally there are scripts and such on the box that typically manage these files so I would expect that none of this would occur using non-standard locations on 5.x vs. 6.x.

Comment: I went through 5.5 up to 5.8 and none of them have 70-persistent-net.rules either. Looking for a pre 5.5 but I'm going to expect that they wouldn't have it either at this point.

Comment: @slm: Thanks again. I have to start brushing up on CentOS and RHEL. RHEL 3 was a long time ago. After that it was a long period for me with only Microsoft servers :(

Comment: I deal with those on a daily basis too 8-(.