# How can I change the default "ens33" network device to old "eth0" on Fedora 19?

Tags: linux, networking, fedora

I've just installed a Fedora 19 on VMware workstation 9.
The default network device is "ens33" instead of "eth0" on RHEL.

The reason I have to use "eth0" is that the license component of one of our products has be to be linked with "eth0".

There are some posts discussing about similar issues, most of which are for older OS.
I haven't found one that exactly match my situation.

Comment: Fedora 19 is significantly different from RHEL 5.5 as in [the question this was marked a duplicate of](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75427/rhel-creating-stable-names-for-network-interfaces), and the answer isn't the same.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The easiest way to restore the old way Kernel/modules/udev rename your ethernet interfaces is supplying these kernel parameters to **Fedora 19**:

1. **net.ifnames=0**
2. **biosdevname=0**

To do so follow this steps:

1. Edit **/etc/default/grub**
2. At the end of **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX** line append "**net.ifnames=0
   biosdevname=0**"
3. Save the file
4. Type "**grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg**"
5. Type "**reboot**"

If you didn't supply these parameters during the installation, you will probably need to adjust and/or rename interface files at **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-***.

Up to **Fedora 18**, just **biosdevname=0** was enough.

As an example, in a certain machine, in a exhaustive research, I got:

-No parameters: NIC identified as "**enp5s2**".
-Parameter biosdevname=0: NIC identified as "**enp5s2**".
-Parameter net.ifnames=0: NIC identified as "**em1**".
-Parameter net.ifnames=0 AND biosdevname=0: NIC identified as "**eth0**".

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed steps!  Everything MathWorks was providing me was for much older versions of Fedora.

Comment: @dr-watson: Up to Fedora 14, **ethX** was the default naming for ethernet interfaces. In Fedora 15, the [Consistent Network Device Naming](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ConsistentNetworkDeviceNaming) was implemented. From Fedora 15 up to 18, just **biosdevname=0** was enough to keep ethX naming. You are welcome.

Comment: This solution also works on Fedora 20. Thanks.

Comment: Also worked on Fedora 21

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 as well.

Comment: Worked on CentOS 7

Comment: And Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial (see [here](https://github.com/geerlingguy/packer-ubuntu-1604/issues/1#issuecomment-213130111) for how I used it with Packer for a Vagrant base box).

Comment: 7 years after, I just installed **Fedora 32** and these parameters are still working.
I (still) prefer supplying them at installation moment, in the kernel's command line.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this using a udev rule, like so:

```bash
cat > /etc/udev/rules.d/99-rename-to-eth0.rules << EOF
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="$(cat /sys/class/net/ens33/address)", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. For others, it's worth noting that the `/sys/class/net/ens33` may be different depending on the values returned by the bios and found in the output of `lspci -vv | grep -A25 Ethernet`. Also, if the intention is to use `eth0` as the name then it may be more appropriate to just specify the kernel boot flags to disable the "predictable" naming of the device.

Answer (score 8):

In Fedora 20, things seem to have changed a bit further.

1) grub kernel arguments
 Yes, both "net.ifnames=0" and "biodevame=0" seem necessary.

2) /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX
Yes, these are necessary, too.

3) /etc/udev/rules.d/60-net.rules
If you have multiple interfaces and want to control naming of each device rather than letting the kernel do in its own way, /etc/udev/rules.d/60-net.rules seems necessary to override /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-net.rules like the following.

`# PCI device 0x1011:0x0019 (tulip)
{SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:c0:f0:4c:f5:78", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"`

`# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="60:a4:4c:b5:26:48", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"`

4) `yum remove biosdevname` seems unecessary.

Comment: Thanks for breaking down the various factors. It seems you have a typo in the #1 point, should be "biosdevname" not "biodevame".

Answer (score 3):

While the accepted answer does provide a solution that works, it does not explain why `ens33` is being used. The links below provide background on why the network device is named something other than `eth0` and how it's now named in RHEL 7 variants:

- [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) - Explains the "why" well
- [CHAPTER 8. CONSISTENT NETWORK DEVICE NAMING](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/ch-Consistent_Network_Device_Naming.html) - RedHat (RHEL7) document explaining all the rules (see section 8.9 for disabling instructions)

It's also worth noting that the values like "33" that appear in `ens33` come from the PCI adapter slot value as returned by the BIOS. Use this command to see what values your system has listed for "Physical Slot":

```
lspci -vv | grep -A20 Ethernet
```

Additional information on the "ens" part of the name can be found in the [udev source code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c#L20).

Answer (score 2):

This is different in Fedora 19 than in previous releases. There are two things to address:

1. Remove biosdevname if it is installed. (`yum remove biosdevname`, or put `-biosdevname` in your kickstart.
2. Disable the udev rule: `ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-name-slot.rules`

More info can be found at http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/SystemdPredictableNetworkInterfaceNames

Answer (score 1):

For Fedora-24:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub`
2. At the end of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line append `net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0`
3. Save the file
4. Type

   ```
   grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg"
   ```

   or type

   ```
   grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
   ```
5. Type `reboot`

Comment: Why does the network device completely disappear from the system if I apply this method to Fedora 26? `ifconfig` only returns `lo` and `virbr0`, but originally `enp4s0` is no longer there.

Comment: To answer myself: need to be careful to change all network scripts to be used with `ethN` naming to use that convention. I had left `enp4s0` in one script.