# Change name of em1 to eth0 in Fedora 19?

Tags: fedora, ethernet

I have already followed the instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81834/how-can-i-change-the-default-ens33-network-device-to-old-eth0-on-fedora-19)
but it doesn't seem to work, as my ifconfig output still shows the same "em1","em2" and "lo". I just need a way to rename one of these to eth0 in Fedora 19, since other methods dont seem to work. Matlab needs eth0 to activate, and I am stuck.

Comment: That other question shouldn't have been marked as a duplicate of a RHEL 5.5 question. It still doesn't have a proper answer, but is really the same question as this one.