# Arch Linux on Virtualbox Internet Connection Issue on VirtualBox

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, internet

I have successfully installed Arch Linux on VirtualBox but the internet is not working in it.
There was no issue with the internet connection during the installation but when I boot from the virtual hard drive (using syslinux bootloader) I'm unable to connect to the internet.

When I boot from the installation CD and mount the root partition and then use installed system from `# arch-chroot` internet works well without doing anything at all and `# ip link` shows two interfaces `lo` and `eth0`

When I try to use `# systemctl enable dhcpcd@enp3s0.service` command, it gives an error 'Operation failed: No such file or directory however `# ip link` says there are two interfaces `lo` and `enp3s0`.

I want to know why there are two different names for the same ethernet port? and more important how do I solve this problem?

Comment: `lo` is a [loopback interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_Loopback_Interface_.28TCP.2FIP.29).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Installing Archlinux as a Guest on Virtualbox**

March 15, 2013 11:54 pm

Essentially, you can follow this guide, but there are several additional steps to take.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Installation

To fix the network:

```
/usr/sbin/dhcpcd enp0s3 to check that you can load the dhcp client.
ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd@.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dhcpcd@enp0s3.service'
change the references to eth0 in /etc/ifplugd/ifplugd.conf
create a profile for enp0s3 in /etc/network.d/interfaces by copying the example (this seems to be overwritten by the netcfg-auto-wired).
start and enable the auto service with systemctl
```

Remember that you can’t get packages from the net without the network :(

**Relevant Links**

Beginner’s Guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide#Installation
Fixing the network: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1243601

Comment: This worked!!! but would you let me know why ethernet port is eth0 when i use arch-chroot and why enp0s3 when i boot from bootloader

Comment: Due to the new udev version, the devices will be renamed by default to
names like enp0s3. This is not done by the kernel and no driver issue,
just a renaming at boot time done by udev.
Source: http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/gentoo-user-virtualbox-guest-eth0-enp0s3-problem-help-210911012.html

Comment: 6/2/14, almost a year later and this works for me. Thank you.

Comment: @vfbsilva If you want the eth0 instead of enp0s3 then you need to add `net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0` to every line that contains `/boot/vmlinuz-linux` in the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` So all those lines should be similar to `linux    /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=8bfcc0b4-e13e-4d56-8eb9-85cd22f950cb rw net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 quiet` . But please note that the arch community strongly discourages this. see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81834/how-can-i-change-the-default-ens33-network-device-to-old-eth0-on-fedora-19

Comment: @Matt this is arch linux, you setup the distro as you wish. Why would it be enabled by default is the right question. Why to load any service by dfefault in fact?

Comment: @vfbsilva well because I did not have to do this when installing it on a host PC. BTW, I was installing Manjaro, both times.

Comment: @Matt manjaro is not arch hence your comment makes no sense.

Comment: @vfbsilva Manjaro is derived from arch. But anyway, I had the same problem and solved it the same way as here. So, hence my interrogation about enabling dhcpcd.

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into the same problem. Solution turned out simple: 
`systemctl start dhcpcd.service`

Everything (ping, pacman, etc.) started working after that.

BTW: `# systemctl enable dhcpcd@enp3s0.service` has a typo. Should be enp0s3. Explains your No such file or directory error ;)