# What lspci command line switch will limit output to just "Ethernet" devices?

Tags: linux, pci

Trying to see if it's possible to limit the output of the `lspci` command to show only Ethernet devices. The `-d` switch seems like it should work, but nothing I've tried gets the job done. For example:

```
lspci -d '*:*:02'
```

still shows *all* pci device classes. I'm using `02` as the class per the values found here: http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PD/02

For reference here is the "man lspci" info for the `-d` switch:

> **-d [<vendor>]:[<device>][:<class>]**
>                 Show  only  devices  with  specified  vendor, device and class ID. The ID's are given in hexadecimal and may be omitted or
>                 given as "*", both meaning "any value".

I'm currently using grep to filter output, and that gets the job done:

```
lspci -vv | grep -A20 Ethernet
```

Answer (score 8):

If you'll remove the `*` and extend the class value to 4 digits the required result will be achived

```
$ lspci -d ::0200
81:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
81:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
```

Update: Class based filter works only with pciutils v3.3.0 or later (see [changelog](https://github.com/pciutils/pciutils/blob/master/ChangeLog)). For RHEL/CentOS this means 7.3 or newer.

Comment: Confirmed this works. In my case, it gives the same output as the answer from LogicalMethods using `lspci -d :07b0`. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Worked great for me on Ubuntu 16.04. Wish the docs said this!

Answer (score 3):

`man lspci` in my system doesn't show that -d option can be used to show classes, but you can get their names in machine-readable mode, thus grepping it. I.e.:

```
$ lspci -vmm | grep -B1 -A2 '^Class.*Ethernet'
Slot:   08:00.0
Class:  Ethernet controller
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
```

Another option would be to use sysfs directly. I.e. you can find all ethernet devices by 'c02' string in modalias:

```
$ find /sys/devices/ -name modalias | xargs grep -l c02
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/modalias
                                          ^^^ PCI port
```

or by using systool:

```
$ systool -b pci -A modalias | awk '
     /modalias.*c02/ { 
          system("/sbin/lspci -s " dev); } 
     { dev = $1; }'
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'm actually looking for the "Physical Slot:" value as provided by `lspci -vv` to use in the answer I posted to this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339280/69122

Comment: So the solution using `systool` to find the `dev` value for `-s` will give me the output I want if I also pass `-vv` to the `lspci` command. BTW, nice example of leveraging `awk` on that one!

Answer (score 3):

To get the results you want you will need to use the pci IDs that are found here rather than the one you were using:

http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/

for instance for a vmware ethernet controller the command would be:

```
lspci -d :07b0
```

Comment: Confirmed that works. Thanks for the alternative. I'll need to alias that command as `07b0` isn't something that going to stick in my mind particularly!