# Why is my wlan device being renamed?

Tags: linux, wifi, network-interface

This is a selection from my `dmesg`:

```
rtl8192cu 1-3:1.0 wlx10bef501e1cd: renamed from wlan0
wlx10bef501e1cd: authenticate with 90:94:e4:e7:99:cc
wlx10bef501e1cd: send auth to 90:94:e4:e7:99:cc (try 1/3)
wlx10bef501e1cd: authenticated
wlx10bef501e1cd: aborting authentication with 90:94:e4:e7:99:cc by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

Where that particular error is linked to device names being too long a string, as probably emerges by this attempt at connection:

```
___@DESK:~$ sudo iwconfig wlx10bef501e1cd essid dlink_DIR-506L key s:___{pass}___
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
    SET failed on device wlx10bef501e1cd ; Invalid argument.
```

The dongle as in the output of `lsusb` is a:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2001:3308 D-Link Corp. DWA-121 802.11n Wireless N 150 Pico Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
```

At the same time, **that device (a wifi usb dongle) was used to successfully install Debian as a net install, with the same long string being the id** showed by the installation GUI during download of the packages.

I tried to rename the device by creating a rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` without success (I used at the output of `udevadm info` and saved the attempt below amongst others, where "1-3" is the third device on bus one).

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ACTION=="add",DRIVERS=="usb",ATTRS{product}=="802.11n WLAN Adapter",ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0",ATTR{type}=="1",KERNEL=="1-3",NAME="wlan1"
```

---

**Why is that device being renamed to such a problematic id in the first place? Instead of trying to patch the situation later down the line is there a way I can just avoid `wlan0` to be renamed?**

---

After accepting an answer for this question I realized the answers for [How can I change the default “ens33” network device to old “eth0” on Fedora 19?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81834/how-can-i-change-the-default-ens33-network-device-to-old-eth0-on-fedora-19]) include the solution for this problem, but the process described there also include steps that are not strictly required to solve this question.

I'm not sure if this qualifies as a duplicate or not.

Comment: Your udev rule is wrong (use `SUBSYTEM=="net"` or you'll be renaming the raw usb device, not the network interface. Note you need to match on several hierarchy levels, so `DRIVERS` *may* be wrong). I've no idea *why* you get such a long name, the usual suspect is rules provided by systemd. And a udev rule with higher priority is how to avoid id.

Comment: @dirk I was using SUBSYTEM=="net" without getting any results, what do you think should be the correct rule and in which file should I save it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's being renamed so that it has a consistent name regardless of what order network devices are probed/connected (otherwise, if you had two USB wifi devices, which is wlan0 and wlan1 would potentially change every boot — or when doing it by MAC address, replacing a NIC suddenly made eth0 become eth1 causing all kinds of failure). More details & rationale can be found at https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

To disable it, Debian provides two methods. Quoting from `/usr/share/doc/udev/README.Debian.gz`):

> - Put "net.ifnames=0" into the kernel command line (e. g. in
>     /etc/default/grub's GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, then run "update-grub").
> - Disable the default *.link rules with
>     "ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link"
>     and rebuild the initrd with "update-initramfs -u".

The name shouldn't have anything to do with iwconfig failing.

Comment: duplicate? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81834/how-can-i-change-the-default-ens33-network-device-to-old-eth0-on-fedora-19/88619#88619

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Could be, though it's a different distro.

Comment: @derobert I don't know what the expected behavior should be, but after adding "net.ifnames=0"to the grub configuration and obtaining a device named with a shorter string now I can connect to the internet without an itch

Comment: I'm sure that renaming the device to any other short id would have worked, but since this is my own home desktop I fell confident just using it as is for now