# Can't connect to Wi-Fi on Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I just started using Kali Linux. I can't download any git clones or any drivers, and I have determined this is likely because I am not connected to the Internet. I booted Kali Linux from a USB. When I type 'iwconfig' wlan0 does not appear.

How do I connect to a wireless network on Kali Linux?

UPDATE:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid any
```

then restart
then enter this:
`sudo apt install firmware-`{your driver for example firmware-`realtek`}

Comment: Kali is known to have troubles with many WLAN drivers. The simplest solution, in particular for inexperienced users, is **not** to use Kali, but instead use a proper Linux distro that will work out of the box (Kali is Debian based, so e.g. another Debian-based one like Ubuntu). You'll have all the hacking tools Kali has, but none of the trouble. Kali is not "what the experts use", not matter what you read on some forums. Kali is designed for [penetration testing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me).

Answer (score 3):

Use the same troubleshooting you would use with [Debian 9](https://www.debian.org/); run `ip -a` and look for the real name of the wireless port, because wlan0 is not a likely port name for Debian going on six years now: See the answer at [Why is my wlan device being renamed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491754/why-is-my-wlan-device-being-renamed) for an explanation. `iwconfig` is also depreciated, being replaced with [iw](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw).

Run `iw dev PORTNAME link` for information about the wlan interface.

Run `iw PORTNAME connect foo` to connect to wireless LAN **foo**, unless WPA or WPA2 security is in use, then use [wpa-supplicant](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#wpa_supplicant).

Comment: Thank you for the response! Where exactly is the name of the port, though? I tried 'ip -a' and all I got were a bunch of words I don't understand. What exactly am I looking for here? Thank you!

Comment: Matthew, if you don't understand the output of `ip -a` then Kaii is not for you yet. Use Ubuntu instead which is much more user friendly.